# full-text index returns incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I created a full-text index on a text column and subsequent contains queries return results that don't include the search term. An example query is:

```
SELECT TOP 10 serial_no,writer_id,myField,assignment_type,subdate,title
FROM writing WHERE contains(myField,'"take it once"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen after you update/rebuild the full text index?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326034.aspx

Comment: Yes.. One of the results contains the query string and the rest don't.

Comment: It looks like since your query contains at least one noise word (it) this behavior can be expected: http://www.dbtalk.net/microsoft-public-sqlserver-fulltext/contains-not-returning-exact-phrase-165617.html